# LINK Error while using C++ library (ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL)

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2015

I am coding some games in C++ and have to use a graphical engine called PlayLib, made in the university near me, but unfortunately when I run this Main.cpp file with all the "includes" and "additional libraries", it gives me the same error! (on Visual Studio 2015, while on VC++2010 it works normally - but I prefer the first one). The error output message is the following:

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' due to '/LTCG' specification
1>Main.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:LBR' specification
1>PlayLib.lib(Graphics.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1900' in Main.obj
1>PlayLib.lib(Graphics.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in Main.obj
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>PlayLib.lib(Graphics.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__vsprintf
1>PlayLib.lib(Graphics.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (__imp_??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z)
1>c:\users\casa\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BatalhaNaval\Debug\BatalhaNaval.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

The main.cpp and header.h are all correct, so I think the problem may lie on the project settings or on the library itself. Please help me so I can work on my Battleship game - I am desperate to put my hands on it haha

Thanks - Guilherme

Answer (score 0):

LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs

I had same warning using some libraries. What helped me was going through #include directives in whole project and changing old style includes to a new style ones:
for example: 
 math.h i had to change to  cmath
stdio.h, to cstdio ad so on.

If that doesn't help then probably you have an issue with runtime libraries. If you use visual studio you can play with them in project properties->C/C++->Code generation->Runtime Libraries.